# Can MSBuild's WriteCodeFragment be used with non-string parameters?

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-assembly

I am trying to use WriteCodeFragment in MSBuild to write the assembly attribute [EnvironmentPermissionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.environmentpermissionattribute.environmentpermissionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).  This takes a parameter of type SecurityAction, which is not a string.  WriteCodeFragment's assembly attributes seems to only support strings.  In there any way to write EnvironmentPermissionAttribute?  I know this tag is deprecated in .net 4, but I am porting some legacy code.

Currently WriteCodeFragment is generating:

```
[assembly: System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermissionAttribute(“System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.RequestMinimum”)]
```

I need it to generate:

```
[assembly: System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermissionAttribute(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.RequestMinimum)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a very good answer, but no, I haven't found a way to write non-string parameters. I ran ILSpy against the task, and it looks like it generates attribute parameters as `CodePrimitiveExpression` objects that wrap strings.